# False-positive predicate function type check in Flow for a function that returns negation of its argument

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This code:

```
type Predicate = any => boolean;

const xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const isEven = (x: number): boolean => x % 2 === 0;
const filter = (pred: Predicate) => (xs: Array<number>) => xs.filter(pred);

filter(isEven)(xs);
```

is considered fine by Flow. This code, however:

```
type Predicate = any => boolean;

const xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = (pred: Predicate) => (xs: Array<number>) => xs.filter(pred);

filter(x => -x)(xs);
```

is also considered fine. It's weird because a function `x => -x` will never return a boolean. If I'm more specific about the argument type in Predicate and say that it has to be a number, like

```
type Predicate = number => boolean;

const xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = (pred: Predicate) => (xs: Array<number>) => xs.filter(pred);

filter(x => -x)(xs);
```

then I get Flow to show some relevant errors, just like it should:

```
6: filter(x => -x)(xs);
                ^ Cannot call `filter` with function bound to `pred` because number [1] is incompatible with boolean [2] in the return value.
References:
1: type Predicate = number => boolean;
                    ^ [1]
1: type Predicate = number => boolean;
                              ^ [2]
```

At the same time, if I try to make that function return something of a more prominent type, Flow finds the problem. These calls are all correctly considered by Flow as containing type errors:

```
filter(x => String(x))(xs); // <- string is incompatible with boolean, okay
filter(x => Number(x))(xs); // <- number is incompatible with boolean, also okay
filter(x => +x)(xs); // <- +x will always evaluate into a number or NaN, never a boolean
filter(x => x & x)(xs); // <- number is incompatible with boolean
```

Is there a way to do a type check for that particular case `x => -x` and get Flow to show errors? Or does Flow do type checking correctly in this case, and it's just me missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generic type as the following can help here

```
type Result<T> = Array<T> => Array<T>;

const xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = <T>(pred: (T) => boolean): Result<T> => xs => xs.filter(pred);

filter(x => -x)(xs);
```

Try it in flow: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQHxQLxQEEAnIgQxEx1x2LIuwG4AoJgYwHsA7eYKAD3h4oAbQCMAGigAmSQGZJAFkkBWSQDYAusw7deAMwCWqCESGUAFGCIQAJgC4o5jAEo8OAEbt2yCKU7OHOCRUSjd+QWpwgDpDYyJLaxtnZiZY4BNzPjCAWj5nTPhkoA